# Inconsistencies with how MySQL stores INT?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, numeric, sqldatatypes

In many of my MySQL database tables, I have been storing timestamps (from the php `time()`) in `int UNSIGNED` fields. However, `time()` returns 13 digit values if I recall correctly, and `INT UNSIGNED` stores values up to `2147483647` which is only 10 digits in length. Therefore any value returned by `time()` will be too large a number to be stored in an `int` field.

However, none of my timestamps have been truncated, so how is it able to store such large values? Is it a database inconsistency or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1343399732 seconds has currently elapsed since the epoch (1970) , which can well be stored in a signed int.

It's dealing with seconds related to around the year [2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) that will start cause you trouble when you store the seconds in a signed 32 bit int.

Comment: nos, your answer is invalid, actually 1343399803 seconds has currently elapsed since the epoch. :]

Comment: Ahh I must have miscounted the digits.. So this is the infamous y2k38 problem? Surely a quick fix for that (though not glamorous) would be to change the field type to `BIGINT UNSIGNED` when the time comes?